# How does #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE tag work in HLS m3u8 file

Tags: http-live-streaming, m3u8

I'm inspecting about `#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE` tag in m3u8 file of HLS.
(https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-23#section-4.3.3.3)
Does somebody can explain the working way of it?

For example, let's suppose that m3u8 file is made for live streaming like below,
After 2 seconds segment1.060.ts, file.000.ts will be gone from list and #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag too.
after all file.001.ts is going to be first media segment in the list.

At this state, what sequence number should be in `#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE`, `#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE`?
`#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY` should be put in front of file.001.ts line again?

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:60
#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2

#EXTINF:0.933600,
segment1.060.ts

#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY
#EXTINF:0.966911,
file.000.ts

#EXTINF:1.000489,
file.001.ts
```

Answer (score 18):

The reason why `EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE` must be used for synchronization across variants is explained in the standard:

> A client **MUST NOT** assume
>      that segments with the same Media Sequence Number in different Media
>      Playlists contain matching content

and

> A client **MUST NOT** assume that segments with the same Media Sequence
>      Number in different Variant Streams or Renditions have the same
>      position in the presentation; Playlists **MAY** have independent Media
>      Sequence Numbers.  Instead, a client **MUST** use the *relative position
>      of each segment on the Playlist timeline and its Discontinuity
>      Sequence Number to locate corresponding segments*.

Back to your question:

- `EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY` marks a discontinuity between two *consecutive* segments. Your discontinuity is between `segment1.060.ts` and `file.000.ts`. There is no discontinuity between `file.000.ts` and `file.001.ts` so no need to re-insert the tag
- each time you remove a `EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY` from the playlist you must increment the `EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE`
- each time you remove a segment from the playlist you must increment the `EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE`

Comment: As the way I understood, the below is correct? 

(after 2s)   **#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:62,    #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:1**
(after 3s)   **#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:63,    #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:1**
(after 4s)   **#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:64,    #EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE:1**

Thanks for your concern on my q.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. From 4.3.3.3 in the spec, it indicates that EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE will always be assumed to be 0 on the first media segment if the tag is not present. If I am understanding correctly, we can imply that the value of the EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY-SEQUENCE tag will ALWAYS be constant across all variant streams (please correct me if I am wrong).